# Redirect happens before onClick() on REACT { Link }

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, onclick

Redirect happens before onClick() on REACT { Link }

Hello. I'm trying the whole day to play a sound onClick Button Event. It works when I remove the Link (URL), but with the Link, the page goes to the new URL without firing the onClick event.
I already tried like this: onClick={() => this.playAudioHandler}.
I really appreciate if someone can fix my code in order to fire the “playAudioHandler” before going to the new URL.

This is my actual code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import classes from "./Button.module.css";
import clickSound from "../assets/click.mp3";

class Button extends Component {
  playAudioHandler = (event) => {
    const audioEl = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0];
    audioEl.play();
    // event.preventDefault();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <audio className="audio-element">
          <source src={clickSound}></source>
        </audio>
        <Link to={this.props.linkToGo}>
          <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={this.playAudioHandler}
            className={[classes.Button, classes[this.props.btnType]].join(" ")}
            // join() to transform the array in a string
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </button>
        </Link>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

Comment: Why do you have the `Link` component wrapping the button? When you click the button, it would also fire the click event on the link, making the page change. If you just want the button to play the sound, the Link component is not necessary.

Comment: So do you want to both play the sound and then change the page?

Comment: I don't want the button just to make a sound. This would be easy. I want to change the page when the button is clicked. But I want the "playAudioHandler " to be execute before it changes the URL. This is the "props.linkToGo" from the parent component:
          <Button linkToGo="/secondpage" btnType="SomeClass">
            COMEÇAR
          </Button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link is firing each click because is the way it works. In your case, button is wrapped by Link, so Link gets fired.
An easy way to achieve that is to avoid using Link and, since looks like your are using `react-router-dom`.

```js
<button
   type="submit"
   onClick={this.playAudioHandler}
   className={[classes.Button, 
   classes[this.props.btnType]].join(" ")}
>
   {this.props.children}
</button>
```

And your handler will redirect after sound was played:

```js
playAudioHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const audioEl = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0];
    audioEl.play();

    const waitSecs = 3000 // 3 secs
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.push('/url');
      OR
      window.location.href = 'url'
    }, waitSecs);
  };
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much. Interesting.
I did like this:
  playAudioHandler = (event) => {
    const audioEl = document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0];
    audioEl.play();
    // event.preventDefault()
    const waitSecs = 300; // 3 secs
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = "coronaquiz";
    }, waitSecs);
  };

Very interesting. When I tried const waitSecs = 100 it didn't work. It's just a question of pausing it enough to play the sound.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped you! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

How about trying setting a state that defines where to redirect and setting that state inClick the button:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import classes from "./Button.module.css";
import clickSound from "../assets/click.mp3";

class Button extends Component {
    constructor(super) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            redirect: null
        }
 }
 playAudioHandler = (event) => {
      const audioEl = 
   document.getElementsByClassName("audio-element")[0];
    audioEl.play();
    // event.preventDefault()
     this.setState({ redirect: this.props.linkToGo })
 };
 render() {
      if (this.state.redirect) {
       return <Redirect to={redirect} />
   }
   return (
  <>
    <audio className="audio-element">
      <source src={clickSound}></source>
    </audio>

      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={ this.playAudioHandler}
        className={[classes.Button, 
        classes[this.props.btnType]].join(" ")}
        // join() to transform the array in a string
      >
           {this.props.children}
           </button>

           </>
        );
    }
}

export default Button;
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the try. The same problem. It redirects without playing the sound. If I receive an "fake" URL as props, the sound plays, but, of course, it does't redirect. The function to play the sound is working perfectly. The problem is that it redirects without playing the sound. I wonder if there is a way of obligation react to execute .play() before it redirects...

Comment: You might be able to sort it out my way but using a shirt timeout to execute the setState for redirection

Comment: I used a mix of your solution with Adolfo Onrubia solution.

I used you suggestion with "import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";" PLUS     const waitSecs = 300;
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.href = "coronaquiz";
    }, waitSecs);